# read an image, resize it and resave it : corona SDK

Tags: android, image, coronasdk, save

In one of my apps in corona SDK, I have an image named `home.png (480x380 px)` with my application files. I want to read that image, resize it (to 240 x 240), and save the new one as a png file with specific name.

Any advice is appreciable...

Comment: do you want to save it in same directoru where home.png lies? Because that is impossible with corona

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı: No, I want to save it anywhere in the Resources Library.

Comment: http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/image-resize-and-crop-saved-file
this may help

Answer (score 0):

At the momment you can't resize images to the size you want in Corona but you can use **display.save()** instead.

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/save.html

> I want to save it anywhere in the Resources Library

No you can't save anything in Resources directory use system.DocumentsDirectory instead.

More info:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/pathForFile.html